# In-App billing of digital goods without Google Play App

Tags: android, security, google-api, in-app-purchase

The current flow of in-app billing is that the Google Play App processes and conveys all billing details between the Android app and the Google Play server, so they never communicate directly.

Why is this restriction in place? Why can't the app directly communicate with the APIs exposed in the Google Play server, like to get details regarding the cause of the restriction. Can we ask the user to Sign in with Google account on the app and make the in-app billing call to server?